# Call a subclass method without casting the object

Tags: c++, inheritance, subclass

I have a class structure looking like this:

```
class A {
public:
     A();

     virtual void doSomething() {
         qDebug() << "Hello from class A";
     }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B();

    void doSomething() {
        qDebug() << "Hello from class B";
    }
};

class C : public A {
public:
    C();

    void doSomething() {
        qDebug() << "Hello from class C";
    }
};
```

Somewhere else I have a method like this:

```
void doSomethingElse(const A argument = A()) {
    argument.doSomething();
}
```

Everytime `doSomethingElse` is called I get the "Hello from class A" output, even if I pass an instance of class B or C as the argument.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Pass by reference instead.

Comment: Read about [object slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs to be passed by reference:

```
void doSomethingElse(const A& argument = A()) {
    argument.doSomething();
}
```

If you don't pass by reference, then the parameter becomes a copy of the argument, and only the `A` part of the argument is copied.  `doSomething()` is then being called on an `A`, and not the object you originally passed as an argument.